# Desserialização de JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, rest

Estou com dificuldade para desserializar este JSON:

```
  string json = "{\"Cidade\":[\"Arrio do Sal\",\"Atl\\u00e2ntida\",\"Bom Princ\\u00edpio\",\"Brochier\",\"Cachoeirinha\",\"Canaos\",\"Canela\",\"Canoas\",\"Cap\\u00e3o da Canoa\",\"Cidreira\",\"Distrito Morungava\",\"Eldorado Do Sul\",\"Esteio\",\"Florian\\u00f3polis\",\"Governador Celso De Ramos\",\"Gramado\",\"Gravata\\u00ed\",\"Gua\\u00edba\",\"Imb\\u00e9\",\"Ivoti\",\"Montenegro\",\"Nova Petr\\u00f3polis\",\"Nova Santa Rita\",\"Nova Tramanda\\u00ed\",\"Novo Hamburgo\",\"Os\\u00f3rio\",\"Pinhal\",\"Porto Alegre\",\"S\\u00e3o Francisco De Paula\",\"S\\u00e3o jos\\u00e9 do Herval\",\"S\\u00e3o Leopoldo\",\"Sapucaia Do Sul\",\"Terra De Areia\",\"Torres\",\"Tramanda\\u00ed\",\"Triunfo\",\"Viam\\u00e3o\"]}";
```

Já tentei de diversas formas utilizando a biblioteca NewtonSoft.

Criei uma classe `Cidade` para desserializar em um objeto, criei uma classe `Cidadeitem` que é uma `List` de objetos da classe `Cidade`, tentei desserializar em uma `List<String>`, tentei com `Dictionary`, todos sem sucesso. O erro reportado é esse:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ApiVistaConsole.CidadeItens]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object.
>
> JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'Cidade', line 1, position
>   10.'

Coloquei direto o retorno JSON aqui para facilitar, mas posso colocar o método que uso para chamar o REST se for ajudar a esclarecer. Já consegui desserializar outras estruturas de JSON mais complexas, mas este array somente de strings realmente não estou conseguindo.

Comment: na verdade a sua classe precisaria ter uma propriedade `string[] Cidade`. Inclua a sua model e o código que está usando para a deserialização.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Para problemas de programação, o melhor é **colocar o código que vc já fez** (em vez de só descrevê-lo), pois isso facilita para todos que forem tentar responder a sua pergunta. Entenda melhor como o site funciona lendo o **[tour]** e a página **[ask]**. Se o código ficou muito grande, pode tentar reduzi-lo para um **[mcve]** <- leia este link, tem dicas legais de como postar o código aqui. Não esqueça também de postar o código como texto (e não como imagem, entenda o motivo [lendo aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052))

Comment: E veja também dicas de formatação na central de ajuda ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)) e no [FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/112052).

Answer (score 1):

Simples, seu objeto tem uma lista de cidades, então fica assim.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"Cidade\":[\"Arrio do Sal\",\"Atl\\u00e2ntida\",\"Bom Princ\\u00edpio\",\"Brochier\",\"Cachoeirinha\",\"Canaos\",\"Canela\",\"Canoas\",\"Cap\\u00e3o da Canoa\",\"Cidreira\",\"Distrito Morungava\",\"Eldorado Do Sul\",\"Esteio\",\"Florian\\u00f3polis\",\"Governador Celso De Ramos\",\"Gramado\",\"Gravata\\u00ed\",\"Gua\\u00edba\",\"Imb\\u00e9\",\"Ivoti\",\"Montenegro\",\"Nova Petr\\u00f3polis\",\"Nova Santa Rita\",\"Nova Tramanda\\u00ed\",\"Novo Hamburgo\",\"Os\\u00f3rio\",\"Pinhal\",\"Porto Alegre\",\"S\\u00e3o Francisco De Paula\",\"S\\u00e3o jos\\u00e9 do Herval\",\"S\\u00e3o Leopoldo\",\"Sapucaia Do Sul\",\"Terra De Areia\",\"Torres\",\"Tramanda\\u00ed\",\"Triunfo\",\"Viam\\u00e3o\"]}";
            RootObject rootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

            var teste = rootObject.Cidade;
        }
    }


    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<string> Cidade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo que você mostrou não representa um objeto `Cidade` que possui uma propriedade `CidadeItem` do tipo `List<string>`.

Ele na verdade é um objeto que possui uma propriedade `Cidade` que pode ser um IEnumerable ou um string[] mesmo.

```
class ExemploModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Cidade { get; set; }
}
```

Agora sim o deserialize vai funcionar:

```
string json = "{\"Cidade\":[\"Arrio do Sal\",\"Atl\\u00e2ntida\",\"Bom Princ\\u00edpio\",\"Brochier\"]}"; //...

var listaCidades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExemploModel>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz no cosoleApplication e funcionou

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stack
{
class Program
{
    public List<string> Cidade { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"Cidade\":[\"Arrio do Sal\",\"Atl\\u00e2ntida\",\"Bom Princ\\u00edpio\",\"Brochier\",\"Cachoeirinha\",\"Canaos\",\"Canela\",\"Canoas\",\"Cap\\u00e3o da Canoa\",\"Cidreira\",\"Distrito Morungava\",\"Eldorado Do Sul\",\"Esteio\",\"Florian\\u00f3polis\",\"Governador Celso De Ramos\",\"Gramado\",\"Gravata\\u00ed\",\"Gua\\u00edba\",\"Imb\\u00e9\",\"Ivoti\",\"Montenegro\",\"Nova Petr\\u00f3polis\",\"Nova Santa Rita\",\"Nova Tramanda\\u00ed\",\"Novo Hamburgo\",\"Os\\u00f3rio\",\"Pinhal\",\"Porto Alegre\",\"S\\u00e3o Francisco De Paula\",\"S\\u00e3o jos\\u00e9 do Herval\",\"S\\u00e3o Leopoldo\",\"Sapucaia Do Sul\",\"Terra De Areia\",\"Torres\",\"Tramanda\\u00ed\",\"Triunfo\",\"Viam\\u00e3o\"]}";

        Cidade cidades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cidade>(json);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Você criou uma classe Cidade ou apenas a propriedade?

Comment: Para o teste eu criei apenas a propriedade.
Porém o ideal seria ter a classe modelo (se for usada em outras parte do código)